# Renderbuffer or texture object after fragment shader?

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on openGL ES2.0 and glsl and I have a question about FBO.
I pass two textures on my openGL ES2.0 code and through glsl shader, particularly fragment shader, I subtract two textures and make a binary image, just like opencv treshold function. My question is that I am not sure if I should use Renderbuffer or texture object for my FBO. I have to choose one since I can only use 1 color attachment (due to restriction of openGL ES2.0). Since the output image after my fragment shader will be a binary image (black or white), shouldn't it be Renderbuffer object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A texture is a series of images which can be read from (via normal texturing means) and rendered into via FBOs. A renderbuffer is an image that can *only* be rendered into.

You should use a renderbuffer for images that you will *only* use as a render target. If you need to sample from it later, you should use a texture.